# How to export materials from Blender for use in another 3d software such as Houdini or Unity?

Tags: texturing, materials

So I made a model with a material that has a complex node system and I want to export that material so that I could apply it to the model. Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: The glTF format (I'm a contributor) can be used to export certain kinds of PBR materials to other systems.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

Answer (score 2):

No, none at all as the rendering pipelines are all different for every package. So unless the other package has a similar shader node, allowing you to re-create the shader, you're out of luck and will have to bake out the various textures for application in the other packages. :-(

Comment: So does this mean that for every other 3d software I want to use I would need to completely recreate all the materials for the object

Comment: Yes. This means exactly that. For every other 3d software you want to use, you would need to completely recreate all the materials for the object in that software unless you are using same render engine in both software packages and even sometimes in that case.